# In what order are the bean instance pools settings applied in Jboss 7.3

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

I have application which deployed in Jboss 7.3.

My application retrieve messages from IBM MQ and sended in HornetQ (in-vm), this messages readed by my app and performed busines logic.

In `jboss-ejb3.xml` i have this config for class which retrieve messages from HornetQ.

```
<mdb:resource-adapter-binding>
    <ejb-name>ProcessMessageHandler</ejb-name>
    <mdb:resource-adapter-name>hornetq-ra</mdb:resource-adapter-name>
</mdb:resource-adapter-binding>
<p:pool>
    <ejb-name>ProcessMessageHandler</ejb-name>
    <p:bean-instance-pool-ref>hq-restriction-handler-pool</p:bean-instance-pool-ref>
</p:pool>
```

And the same time i have in `standalone.xml` for hornetq-ra this config

```
<mdb>
    <resource-adapter-ref resource-adapter-name="hornetq-ra"/>
    <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="query-message-processor-pool"/>
</mdb>
.......

<pools>
    <bean-instance-pools>
        ....
        <strict-max-pool name="query-message-processor-pool" max-pool-size="1" instance-acquisition-timeout="30" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>

<strict-max-pool name="hq-restriction-handler-pool" max-pool-size="6" instance-acquisition-timeout="30" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
        ....
    </bean-instance-pools>
</pools>
....

<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:4.0">
    <server name="default" persistence-enabled="true">
        ...
        
        <pooled-connection-factory name="hornetq-ra" entries="java:/jms/connection_factory_xa" connectors="in-vm" transaction="xa">
            <outbound-config allow-local-transactions="true"/>
        </pooled-connection-factory>
    </server>
</subsystem>
```

**Question** What is the size of the pool intended for the class ProcessMessageHandler if hornetq-ra have `query-message-processor-pool" max-pool-size="1"`  and in ProcessMessageHandler defined own pool `<bean-instance-pool-ref>hq-restriction-handler-pool</p:bean-instance-pool-ref>` which have max-pool-size = 6

I read official documentation for Jboss and ActiveMq but not finded order of applying bean pools